# Weak convergence in $L^p=L^p(\Omega,\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\{f_n\} \subseteq L^p,\{g_n\} \subseteq L^q, f \in L^p,g \in L^q,$ and ${1} \over {p}$ + ${1} \over {q}$$=1$.

Suppose $\|f_n-f\|_p \rightarrow 0$ and $\int_{\Omega} g_n \varphi d\mu \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} g \varphi d\mu$ for every $\varphi \in L^p$.  Then is it true that $\int_{\Omega} f_n g_n d\mu \rightarrow \int_{\Omega}  fg d\mu$ ?

$|\int_{\Omega}f_n g_n d\mu -\int_{\Omega} fg d \mu|=|\int_{\Omega}f_n (g_n-g) d\mu +\int_{\Omega} (f_n-f)g d \mu|\le \int_{\Omega} |f_n||g_n-g| d\mu+\int_{\Omega} |f_n-f| |g| d\mu$

$\int_{\Omega} |f_n-f| |g| d\mu\le ||f_n-f||_{L^p(\Omega)} ||g||_{L^q(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0$ (using Holder's inequality)

For the first integral : $\int_{\Omega} |f_n||g_n-g| d\mu$ in this case can I use weak convergence of g?

Comment: what is $\varphi$?

Comment: I guess any $L^p$ function... By $\to$ do you mean $L^1$ convergence or just the convergence of the integrals as a sequence of numbers?

Comment: See proposition 3.5(iv) in Brezis' Functional Analysis, Sobolev spaces and Partial Differential Equations

Comment: You have this $\varphi$ in there with no explanation.

Comment: my professor said that $f_j \rightarrow f$ in the $\tau_{X^*}$ $X^*-$topology if and only if $|\int f_j \varphi -\int f \varphi | \rightarrow 0, \forall \varphi \in C^{\infty}_c, f_j \in L^p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left| \int f_n g_n - \int fg \right| &= \left| \int f_n g_n - \int f g_n + \int f g_n - \int f g  \right| \\
&=\left| \int g_n (f_n -f )  + \int fg_n - \int fg \right| \\
&\leq \int |g_n||f_n-f| + \left| \int fg_n - \int fg\right|.
\end{align}
$$
Since $\{g_n\}_n$ converges weakly in $L^q$, it is bounded in $L^q$, namely there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $||g_n||_{L^q} \leq C \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
By Holder's inequality, we have
$$
\int |g_n||f_n-f| \leq ||g_n||_{L^q} ||f_n-f||_{L^p} \leq C ||f_n-f||_{L^p} \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$
Since $f\in L^p$, by assumption we have
$$
\left| \int fg_n - \int fg\right| \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
$$
and this concludes the proof.